# contiki ipv6 without rpl, neighbor discovery

Tags: c, contiki

I am actually working on contiki os and I would like to set up an ipv6 network without using rpl. my question is how can I discover neighbours in my radio range. I am looking to 6lowpan nd RA/RS/NA/NS messages but I do not know how to make it to work.
I would like my nodes to get prefix from one of the routers and after send udp packets to my neighbours.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following parameters in your project configuration file:

```
#define NETSTACK_CONF_WITH_IPV6  1
#define UIP_CONF_IPV6_RPL 0
```

The parameters `UIP_CONF_ND6_SEND_RA`, `UIP_CONF_ND6_SEND_NS` and `UIP_CONF_ND6_SEND_NA` are then automatically set which enable the ND protocol.

Use `UIP_CONF_ROUTER=0` to configure the devices as simple node to receive RA message. By default every Contiki nodes are configured as router.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know how can I discover my neighbours?.

Comment: Once NDP is enabled, thanks to the exchange of NS and NA message between the node's interfaces, these later are discovering each others. This is done automatically. Enable the debug in the files `core/net/ipv6/uip-nd6.c`  and `core/net/ipv6/uip-ds6-nbr.c` to see what is happening.

Comment: I've already done it. I have set two routers and they're sending RA but they do not respond to RA messages. Why would be the cause of this? Thanks

Comment: Only hosts respond to RA message. RS output is disabled for routers: https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/3f4436bac9a9f6da0df188372d4374693eab8a52/core/net/ipv6/uip-nd6.c#L799

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. One last question. The scenario that I am working is two routers and one no-router node. The no-router node I set UIP_CONF_ROUTER=0, CONTIKI_WITH_IPV6 = 1 and CONTIKI_WITH_RPL = 0. I am able to discover my neighbors. But from router nodes with UIP_CONF_ROUTER=1. I can not see any router neighbor. Thanks

Comment: The no-router node add routers as neighbor from the reception of the RA message. But a router disable the RA reception. To add a router as a neighbor for a router node, they must first exchange NA/NS message. To do that, one must initiate a communication with the other and perform Address Resolution (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4861#page-61).