# Contiki NG/Cooja - Non-RPL Simulation with No-Root Node

Tags: cooja, contiki-ng, unicast, rpl

Can we simulate in Contiki-NG / Cooja a non-RPL sensor network where each node can directly communicate to any other node, without having to go through any root node?

Comment: I think the answer is yes. referring to this post. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45024461/contiki-ipv6-without-rpl-neighbor-discovery
However, any additional details are appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.